# SQL Query Joining 2 Table And Display Final Result With Both Table Similar Column Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I had 2 tables with a barcode string which both of the table have the value.

Transaction Table

```
ID  | Barcode | Date         | From_Reject
1     Bar01     July 2020   
2     Bar02     July 2020       Yes
3     Bar03     July 2020
```

Reject Table

```
Reject ID | Barcode | Reject Date           | Status 
1            Bar04     August 2020             Active
2            Bar02     September 2020          Reworked
3            Bar05     January 2020            Active
```

Final Result

```
ID    | Reject ID | Barcode | Date       | Reject Date    | From_Reject     | Status
1         null       Bar01    July 2020     null              null             null
2          2         Bar02    July 2020    September 2020     YES             REWORKED
3         null       Bar03    July 2020      null             null             null
null       1         Bar04    null         August 2020        null             Active
null       3         Bar05    null         January 2020       null             Active
```

Is that possible i use left join can achieve that? Because i had try to use left join or outer join both was not show as the final result that i want. Is that any other sql query syntax that can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was originally tagged MySQL.  This provides an answer for both MySQL and for any other database.

Basically you want a `full join`, which MySQL does not support.  I would recommend:

```
select *
from transactions t left join
     rejects r
     using (barcode)
union all
select *
from transactions t right join
     rejects r
     using (barcode)
where t.barcode is null;
```

Note that this query is carefully crafted to use `union all` rather than `union`.  In addition, this is one of the rare situations where `right join` is helpful.  This allows the use of `*`, which returns that columns in the same order for the two subqueries.

If you have a list of `barcodes`, then I would recommend using that with just `left join`s:

```
select *
from barcodes b left join
     transactions t
     using (barcode) left join
     rejections r
     using (barcode);
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server (and just about any other database), you would simply do:

```
select *
from transactions t full join
     rejects r
     on t.barcode = r.barcode
```

Comment: all the table column on both the database table will be show as display right?

Comment: @Marcus . . . Yes.  If you want a subset, list them explicitly.

Comment: i also can add in the where clause where i use to select reject_date or date from august 2020 right?

Comment: i use "using(barcode), but my sql server had showing incorrect syntax

Comment: @Marcus . . . If you are getting a SQL Server error, then you have mis-tagged the question.  Change the tag to SQL Server.  If you have a different question about filtering the results, then ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, explanation, and database tag.

Comment: My bad, for sql can it auto fill up the front barcode with the trx_reject code?

Comment: @Marcus . . . You need to list the columns explicitly, and use `coalesce(t.barcode, r.barcode) as barcode` in the `select`.